# How do you disable the GRCP Server service in Quarkus 2.x?

Tags: grpc, quarkus

I have a GRPC client only application using Quarkus 2.1 and get the following error when the application starts:

```
[io.qua.grp.run.GrpcServerRecorder] (vert.x-eventloop-thread-2) Unable to start the 
gRPC server: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to address /0.0.0.0:9000
        at io.grpc.netty.NettyServer.start(NettyServer.java:268)
        at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:183)
```

How can I disable the GRPC server service and other associated services if I am only interested in the client part? Are there configuration properties that can be set for this?

Comment: The application is running in with the dev profile, so question is regarding dev mode I guess.

Comment: Dev mode has the server enabled by default, even if there's no service. In prod mode, the server won't start if there's no service.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it by flag - `quarkus.grpc.dev-mode.force-server-start=false`
dependency `io.quarkus:quarkus-grpc-deployment`
works for me with `quarkus v2.8.X`